# Different font size/position of beamer's navigation symbols template's content depending on regular/plain frames

Tags: beamer, header-footer

Let's suppose I'd like to divert the `navigation symbols` template (e.g. in order replace them by the frame numbers, see [this bug report](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/520) ;) I would be facing troubles regarding the font size/position, depending on regular/plain frames, as shown by the following MCE.

How could I get rid of these troubles?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A regular frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \frametitle{A plain frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the problem is that the navigation symbols are placed above the footline, which is not there on plain frames. Would you be interested in a brute force tikz solution? (the different font size can be avoided by explicitly setting it `\tiny\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber`)

Comment: @samcarter I see for the reason. About the brute force solution, why not but I would have expected a not too verbose solution to expose to LaTeX newbies :) About the font size, I already tried this, but noticed `\tiny` is larger than the font size in regular frames (okay, I could make use of `\fontsize{...}{...}\selectfont)`).

Comment: I think the reason for the different font size boils down to that if it not explicit set, it uses the font size of whatever element was typeset before and normally that is the footline, but on a plain frame, there is no footline ...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your sentence `\tiny is larger than the font size in regular frames` Could you make an example to show which problem you encounter?

Comment: @samcarter Insert `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}` in the preamble. Then, in the document body: firsrt a regular frame, then `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\tiny\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}` and, finally, another regular frame. You will see "1/2" is smaller than "2/2".

Comment: Ah, now I understand.

Comment: Try with `\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\Tiny\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}` (sorry, I confused `\tiny` with `\Tiny`)

Comment: (I'll never remember that the big T is smaller than the small t :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that there is no special font size set in your redefined `navigation symbols` template. So the fontsize of whatever element was typeset before is used. Normally the footline comes before, but on plain frames there is no footline.

As a workaround you can explicitly set the font size:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\Tiny\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A regular frame}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A plain frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Brute force solution and total overkill: use tikz and position the pagenumber relative to the page

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[xshift=-0.4cm,yshift=0.2cm] at (current page.south east) {\tiny\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{A regular frame}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[plain]
  \frametitle{A plain frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess you meant `\tiny` instead of `\Tiny`.

Comment: No, tiny is bigger than Tiny :) (that was the difference to the normal slides yous aw)

Comment: Another point I'm learning thanks to you: the two extra font sizes `\Tiny` and `\TINY` :)