# Beamer footnote on same level as slide number

Tags: beamer, footnotes, beamer-metropolis

I would like to push the footnote on `beamer` to the very bottom. The slide number is at the very bottom. I want the footnote to be at that level.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Some text\footnotemark
\footnotetext[1]{some footnotetext here, which is not at the same level as slide number}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I tried `\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}` but the footnote disappeared.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Don't use `footmisc` with beamer, they are incompatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recycling some answer I wrote earlier today (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464117/36296):

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
    \ifnum\insertframenumber>0
        \Tiny\insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Some text\footnotemark
\footnotetext[1]{some footnotetext here, which is not at the same level as slide number}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could use the `moloch` theme, a more modern fork of the `metropolis` theme which comes with a much shorter footline:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Some text\footnotemark
\footnotetext[1]{some footnotetext here, which is not at the same level as slide number}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This adds the slide number as zero to my title page slide. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: @Backspace Please see my updated code