# Beamer metropolis no frame number on section pages

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

Following [Beamer footnote on same level as slide number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464135/beamer-footnote-on-same-level-as-slide-number),

I am trying to get my footnote on the same line as the slide numbers.

However, the solution adds numbering to the section pages. How can I get rid of it, but keep it on frames other than title and section frames ?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the same approach as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=2042#a2294

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \hfill\smash{\usebeamerfont{page number in head/foot}\usebeamercolor[fg]{page number in head/foot}\raisebox{0.1cm}{\usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}}~}
}

\setbeamercolor{page number in head/foot}{fg=gray}
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[framenumber]

\begin{document}

\section{title}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{blub}
    abc\footnote{Footnote text.}
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify that answer by removing the frame number:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
    \ifnum\insertframenumber>0
        \relax%
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Some text\footnotemark
\footnotetext[1]{some footnote text here, which is not at the same level as slide number}
\end{frame}

\section{New Section}
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\begin{itemize}
\item this is item zero 
\item and item one ...
\item finally number three ..
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough , but I'd like to keep frame numbers on slides other than title and section frames.

Answer (score 0):

For a simple use, just adding a negative `\vspace{}` to the footnotes is satisfying:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
% \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}


\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \parindent 0em\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \usebeamercolor{footnote}\hbox to 0.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
  \vspace{-.73cm}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain,noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Some text\footnotemark
\footnotetext[1]{some footnote text here, which is not at the same level as slide number}
\end{frame}

\section{New Section}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item this is item zero
\item and item one ...
\item finally number three ..
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Carefull as this solution:

- needs the `vspace{}` to be adjusted depending on the properties of the used template
- can create overlapping if the footnote is too long

Answer (score 0):

Not very nice code, but it works. It suppresses frame numbers before every section page and inserts again after them.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle, numbering=counter]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{%
    \ifnum\insertframenumber>0
         \Tiny\insertframenumber%
    \fi%
}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
    \frame[plain,c,noframenumbering]{\sectionpage}
    \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\Tiny\insertframenumber}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
Some text\footnotemark
\footnotetext[1]{some footnote text here, which is not at the same level as slide number}
\end{frame}

\section{New Section}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item this is item zero 
\item and item one ...
\item finally number three ..
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```