# Customizing Bergen beamer theme

Tags: beamer

Minimal (non-)Working Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetheme{Bergen}
\usecolortheme[named=red]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}\hfill \includegraphics[width=2cm]{Logo.jpg}}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

(Logo.jpg is my University's logo.) Result:

[image]

Aim:

[image]

For the title page, and:

[image]

For other pages. Questions:

1. How do I change the width of the vertical stripe?
2. How do I make said stripe extend into the footline?
3. How do I put the logo on the stripe?
4. How do I change the background?

(Note: Please disregard the size difference of the bottom-right logos, I just need to fix the `width=` in the `\includegraphics` command for that.)

**Update**

With @samcarter's comments, I was able to get the background in:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{background}
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{Background.png}}
\usetheme{Bergen}
\usecolortheme[named=red]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[text line]{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace*{-8pt}\hfill \includegraphics[width=1cm]{Logo.jpg}}}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So question 4 is solved. Her suggestions for 1-2 seem not to work for me. Question 3 is as of now unaddressed.

Comment: Why do you want to customize an existing theme for that? It might be easier to simply create a new one…

Comment: To extend the red stripe to the bottom either use this trick: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464117/36296 or this: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/520#issuecomment-445573463

Comment: To change the width `\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=.15\paperwidth}`

Comment: I don't think using a theme which is based on the `inmargin` inner theme is a good idea for this type of desired result, this will look terrible for itemizations etc. Better use something based on the sidebar theme.

Comment: You don't need `graphicx` with beamer

Comment: @samcarter I'm a total noob at beamer and I don't even know what inner and outer themes are :). OK for graphicx, removing that line. `\setbeamersize` seems not to be working for me: I tried 1cm and 2cm and the result is the same…

Comment: For changing the background image see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78464/background-image-in-beamer-slides

Comment: @TeXnician Because I didn't even know I could create new themes :).

Comment: The choice of Bergen was just because it had the left stripe.

Comment: @samcarter And the two tricks for the widrth seem to do nothing as they are (in fact, `\beamer@sidebarside` seems to be undefined).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a complete theme is exceeding the scope of this website, but here some quick hacks to create something similar:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamertemplate{background}
{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image}}

\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{bg=red!70!black}
\useoutertheme[height=0pt,width=1cm]{sidebar}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \node[xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-0.5cm] at (current page.north east) {\tiny\insertframenumber};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\title[]{title}
\author[]{author names}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{\raisebox{0.2cm}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}}\hspace*{0.2cm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \fill[red!70!black] (current page.south west) rectangle ([xshift=2cm]current page.north west);
        \node at ([xshift=2cm,yshift=-1cm]current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-duck}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
  normal frame
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the theme (file `beamerthemebicocca.sty`):

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\mode<presentation>

%--- Font theme (by default, Beamer loads \usefonttheme{default})

%--- Color theme
\usecolortheme[named=red]{structure}
\setbeamercolor{sidebar}{use=local structure,bg=local structure.fg}

%--- Inner theme (by default, Beamer loads \useinnertheme{default})
% Definition of the logo
\setbeamertemplate{logo}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image}}
% Title page
\addtobeamertemplate{title page}%
  {\thispagestyle{bicocca@navigation@titlepage}}{}
\def\ps@bicocca@navigation@titlepage{%
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar canvas left}{%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{local structure}%
    \vrule width .15\paperwidth height \paperheight}
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}{\vskip 1cm%
    \hskip .1\paperwidth\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}
  \@nameuse{ps@navigation}}
% Background image
\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
  \pgfsetfillopacity{.05} % choose the opacity you wish here
  \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image}
  \pgfsetfillopacity{1}}

%--- Outer theme (by default, Beamer loads \useoutertheme{default})
% No navigation bar
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
% Default side bar (red stripe)
\setbeamersize{sidebar width left=1cm}


\mode<all>
```

and here is an example using the theme:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{bicocca}

\title{My Title}
\author{by Me}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{frame}
  A frame
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You should replace file `example-image` with your logo and adapt the different sizes.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Very nice answer! I guess you can leave out all the `\use...theme{default}`, they should be loaded by default

Comment: @samcarter: added in comments for clarity