# Beamer metropolis theme: How to display logo and text in footer?

Tags: beamer, beamer-metropolis

I'm using metropolis template as the theme for my beamer presentation. I would like to know if and how is possible to put an image with some text in the left border of the footer (for all slides except special ones like title page and standout).

I've seen a lot of solutions in plain beamer but I don't want to broke the style of metropolis that I like very much.

Workable example without the footer.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169, 16pt]{beamer}
\usetheme[titleformat=smallcaps]{metropolis}

% Language and encoding
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\title{My awesome title}
\date{\today}
\author{My name}
\institute{My institute}

\begin{document}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\maketitle
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{Table of contents}
  \setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
  \tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Section}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}{A frame}
  This is a frame
\end{frame}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{frame}[standout]
Thank you!
\end{frame}
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you be so kind and give a minimum working example?

Comment: Done, but I don't know how could it help in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as in every other theme, you could use the `\logo` macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\logo{text \raisebox{-0.5cm}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-duck}}\hspace*{\textwidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The text and the image are not aligned with page numbering.

Comment: @gvgramazio no it's not. If that is what you want, either redefine the fooline or position the image relative to the page using the second codeblock of this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464117/36296

Comment: I will try to do it in that way.